# conventional notation for magnitude and vector

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

Suppose as an example I have the magnitude of an electric 
$\left \| \vec{E} \right \|=\frac{\lambda}{2\epsilon s\pi}$
This is the equivalent to $\vec{E}=\frac{\lambda}{2\epsilon s\pi}\hat{r}$.

Is this correct? But why? I haven't come across this signalling before.

Comment: It depends on the physics of the problem.  Given only the magnitude of the electric field, we cannot assert its direction.

Comment: What if the flux is through a closed surface of a sphere?@Dr.MV
To rephrase it, Gauss's law relates the flux through a closed Gaussian surface to the charge enclosed. Given that one has found the magnitude of the the electric field. How does one then determine the electric field itself?
Would squaring the magnitude of the electric field suffice since the square of a vector field is the square of the magnitude of the vector field itself.

Comment: What is the source of the electric field?  Is this a line charge on the $z$-axis with charge density $\lambda$?  What is $s$?  Is $\hat r$ the radial unit vector in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: The source of the electric field is the charge density of a solid sphere where $\rho$ is the charge per unit volume.
Edit: realised you were enquiring wrt the question
electric field due to a line charge
I found the magnitude of the electric field but wondered if it would be correct for me to rephrase it the way I did in the OP.

Comment: I am confused.  In the OP, there are (i) $\lambda$, (ii) $s$, and (iii) $\hat r$. What are these?  What do they have to do with $\rho$?

Comment: @Dr.MV Forget everything that I've said. I went on a tangent in respond to your first question.
The question asks for the electric field due to a line charge with charge density $\lambda$. Using Gaussian's law, I've found the magnitude of the electric field as posted in the OP. Now, given that I've the magnitude of the electric field, how can I move on to determine the electric field itself@Dr.MV

Comment: Note:s is just the distance of the electric field at the point s from the line charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Notational Preliminaries:**
>
> The cylindrical coordinate variables are $(\rho,\phi,z)$, where $x=\rho \cos \phi$ and $y=\rho \sin \phi$ describe the transformation from cylindrical to Cartesian coordinates.
>
> Furthermore, $(\hat \rho,
> \hat \phi, \hat z)$ represent the unit vector triad in cylindrical coordinates.
>
> Finally, the electric field in general can be written in cylindrical coordiates as $$\vec E=\hat \rho E_{\rho}(\rho,\phi,z)+\hat \phi E_{\phi}(\rho,\phi,z)+\hat  z E_{z}(\rho,\phi,z)$$

Exploit the symmetry of the problem, which you already have done when applying Gauss's Law (not Gaussian's Law).

In your development, you assumed that $\vec E$ has only a radial component $\hat \rho$ and depends only on the radial variable $\rho$.

> This reasoning is based on the physics and geometry of this problem, namely an infinite line charge of uniform density $\lambda$ placed along the $z$ axis.  Since the field source has no dependence on $\phi$ or $z$, then the field is independent of those coordinate variables.  And understanding Coulomb's Law, we see that the field can have no azimuthal or axial components.

Thus, we can write the electric field as $$\vec E=\hat \rho E_{\rho}(\rho)\tag 1$$

Then, you constructed a cylindrical surface with height $L$, centered on the $z$ axis, encompassing part of the line charge.

The total charge $Q$ enclosed is $Q=\lambda \, L$.

Finally, Gauss's Law states $$\oint_S \vec E\cdot \hat n \,dS=Q/\epsilon_0\tag 2$$

Using $(1)$ in $(2)$ reveals

$$\int_0^L\int_0^{2\pi}\hat \rho E_{\rho}(\rho)\cdot \rho \rho d\phi\,dz=\lambda\,L/\epsilon_0\implies E_{\rho}(\rho)=\frac{\lambda }{2\pi\epsilon_0\,\rho} \tag 3$$

> Note that there is no contribution to the flux on the ends of the cylinder since $\vec E$ has no axial component.

Finally, substituting $(3)$ into $(1)$ yields

$$\vec E=\hat \rho \frac{\lambda }{2\pi\epsilon_0\,\rho}$$

Comment: My only issue is with figuring out why the electric field is written the way it is in(1). Is there a formal source for me to familiarised myself with relating to (1)?

Comment: That form is specific for this problem and its symmetries.   I've included notes that discuss the reasoning for arriving at $(1)$.  Please have a read and let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: What is $\vec{E}_{\rho}$? We both agree that the electric field is a function only of the radial component or just the distance away from the line charge. Is it the $\rho$ component of $\vec{E}$?

Comment: There is no $\vec E_{\rho}$.  There is $\vec E =\hat \rho E_{\rho}$.  I am using $\hat \rho =\frac{\hat xx+\hat yy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ as the cylindrical radial unit vector, $\rho =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the cylindrical radial coordinate, and $E_{\rho}(\rho)$ is the cylindrical coordinate radial component of the electric field.  Note that it is a scalar.

Comment: Thanks. Extending this to the case of a solid sphere, the electric field is a function of the radial component, hence,
$\vec{E}$=$E\hat{\rho}$
But IF there is additional dependence on the azimuthal and polar angle then
$\vec{E}$=$E\hat{\rho}$+$E\hat{\theta}$ + $E\hat{\phi}$ right?

Comment: You're welcome.   And yes, but I would use $r$ to label the spherical radial coordinate so as not to confuse it with the cylindrical coordinate $\rho$.